# Erro ao acessar o Storage Firebase no App Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

Estou com um problema ao tentar setar uma imagem do storage no `ImageView` do Android Studio, aparece esse erro no logcat:

> User does not have permission to access this object.
>        Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
>       {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
>       java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}

As regras estão liberadas para todos:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada nas regras, você pode definir se o usuário deve estar logado para acessar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou configura o acesso público:

```
// Anyone can read or write to the bucket, even non-users of your app.
// Because it is shared with Google App Engine, this will also make
// files uploaded via GAE public.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 0
votar contra
accept

Eu deixei a regra liberada para todos service firebase.storage { match /b/{bucket}/o { match /{allPaths=**} { allow read, write: if request.auth == null; } } }

Comment: Tenta assim: `
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
} `

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Eu deixei a regra liberada para todos
service firebase.storage { 
   match /b/{bucket}/o { 
     match /{allPaths=**} { 
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    } 
  }
 }